# Why Does Byte 150 show up as a dash in Notepad but Not when I read it programatically?

Tags: c#, text

I've got a file that looks OK in Notepad (and Notepad++) but when I try to read it with a C# program, the dash shows up as a replacement character (�) instead. After some trial and error, I can reproduce the error as follows:

```
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Misc\\CharTest\\wtf.txt", new byte[] { 150 });
            var readFile = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Misc\\CharTest\\wtf.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(readFile);
```

Now, if you go and look in the wtf.txt file using Notepad, you'll see a dash... but I don't get it. I know that's not a "real" Unicode value so that's probably the root of the issue, but I don't get why it looks fine in Notepad and not when I read in the file. And how *do* I get the file to read it as a dash?

As an aside, a VB6 program I'm trying to rewrite in C# also reads it as a dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File.ReadAllText(string)` overload [defaults to UTF8 encoding](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,783), in which a standalone byte with value 150 is invalid.

Specify the actual encoding of the file, for example:

```cs
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
string content = File.ReadAllText(fileName, encoding);
```

I used the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding, which has a dash at codepoint 150.

---

**Edit:** Notepad displays the file correctly because for non-Unicode files the Windows-1252 codepage is the default for western regional settings. So likely you can use also `Encoding.Default` to get the correct result but keep in mind that `Encoding.Default` can return different code pages with different regional settings.

Comment: Thanks! You're right Encoding.Default works, but only in C# 4.x and earlier. In .Net Core 3, UTF-8 is the default (and I assume this will be true for .Net 5 when it comes out in a few days)

Answer (score 1):

You are writing bytes in a textfile. And the you are reading those bytes and interpret them as chars.
Now, when you write bytes, you don't care about encoding, while you have to, in order to read those very same bytes as char.

Notepad++ seems to interpret the byte as Unicode char and therefore prints the _.
Now [File.ReadAllText reads the bytes in the specified encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1), which you did not specify and there will be set to [one of these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netcore-3.1) and seems to be UTF-8, [where 150 is not a valid entry](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec).